# What could be the possible ways to replace Dynamic query in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario wherein an SP is implemented with Dynamic Query and i need to remove to this implementation due to performance factor. This is an import functionality and we initially insert our data from excel to a staging table and from there we validate our data keeping the data into an another temp table. And then inserting the data into physical tables if all the validation passes.

Staging table can have four category of data(FParty, SParty, TParty, Owner) which is being passed from excel to staging one at a time. And the physical table for these category contains different number of columns. Hence at runtime only we will be able to know the category of data and from then we have to create temp table accordingly to validate the data.

As of now we are using dynamic query to create temp table at run time depending on the category. Procedure is as follow:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetData_Into_Temptbl] (                
     ,@CategoryType varchar(50) -- FParty, SParty, TParty, Owner)
BEGIN
declare Category cursor for
select Fields from dbo.StagingTable where CategoryName= @CategoryType   

Open Category
Fetch Next from Category into @Field


while @@Fetch_status = 0      
begin

set @FieldsToCreatetempTable = @ FieldsToCreatetempTable + ',' + @Field 

Fetch Next from Category into @Field
end
close Category
deallocate Category
set @tblTemp = 'insert into #TempTableData ('+@FieldsToCreatetempTable+')'
Exec(@tblTemp)
END
```

Above code is working fine but need to replace the dynamic nature of the procedure. Kindly suggest any concept.

Comment: Your performance issue is more likely due to the cursor and less due to dynamic SQL. You may want to consider removing the cursor

Comment: I feel like the problem is that you call this procedure over and over again, -- and do row-by-row handling, not that there is dynamic SQL inside it.

Comment: Thanks Raj for bringing this into notice, but i have been asked to remove dynamic query regardless of Cursor :(

Comment: If you only have 4 categories, why not just write 4 stored procs and call the right one logically. `if @categoryType = 'FParty'  exec InsertFPartyTempData ....`

Comment: What could be the values of @FieldsToCreatetempTable? First of all I'd try to get away from row base approach. SQL Server is doing much better with sets... Second I'd avoid a #table and rather use a DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1,col2,...)

Comment: Cargo culting over dynamic SQL isn't going to help you. How many rows are there in `StagingTable` for a given category? Building a temporary table with thousands of columns is not going to work. What are you actually trying to do here? And why do you think using a temporary table is the best way to handle this? And finally, when you're pivoting data, use `pivot` - using a cursor to sum strings up and finally inserting them in a dynamic SQL isn't going to work very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table/cursor to build a comma separated list of columns is overkill, like major overkill.

You could consider unwinding the logic into 4 simple stored procedures, which can be called based on some logic, such as the `categoryType`

```
IF @categoryType = 'FParty'
BEGIN
    exec dbo.InsertFPartyTempData 
END
ELSE IF @categoryType = 'SParty'
BEGIN
    exec dbo.InsertSPartyTempData 
END
... // etc
```

Comment: Thanks Jamiec,this looks to be a simple and good approach for my problem.